# TypeError: data type not understood in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I was working with numpy for Neural Networks and I am facing This Error

> TypeError: data type not understood

and my code was

```
a = np.array([7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7])
print(np.argmax(np.array([[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]]), axis = 0, a))
```

Comment: change `a = np.array([7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7])` to `a = np.array([[7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]])`

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are expecting from `np.argmax(np.array([[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]]), axis = 0, a)`

Comment: @Maran Sowthri go over to this link: ' https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify @dimay 's comment:
np.array receives two inputs, with the first being the data itself, and the second being the datatype. When you want two rows, you should be giving np.array a list of lists.
np.array tried to create a 1-d array with the elements [7, 7, 7], and the other [7, 7, 7] was thought to be a dtype, which leads to the error.